# Reliable way to add nonce to HTTP Header in WordPress?

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, headers, nonce

I am trying to implement CSP on my wordpress site.

Inspired by this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50002041/adding-nonce-to-script-tag I tried to build a way to add nonces to my wordpress site.

```
add_action( 'run_custom_nonce_value', 'custom_nonce_value' );
function custom_nonce_value () {
    $created_nonce = wp_create_nonce();
    define( 'NONCE_RANDVALUE', $created_nonce ); 
}
```

This function was directly taken from the Stackoverflow link mentioned above.

It created Nonce Values using `wp_create_nonce()`

The major problem is that it creates a nonce but doesn't update it. Refreshing my wordpress site still shows the same nonce.

could `global $variable` be better option instead of define?

Anyways, after that the below code is slightly modified and adds the nonce to headers using WP actions and adds nonce to all scripts that are registered.

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_nonce_to_script', 10, 3 );
function add_nonce_to_script( $tag, $handle, $source ) {
    custom_nonce_value();
    $val_nonce = NONCE_RANDVALUE;
    $search = "type='text/javascript'";
    $replace = "type='text/javascript' nonce='".$val_nonce."' ";
    $subject = $tag;

    $output = str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
    return $output;
}

function pagely_security_headers($headers) {
    custom_nonce_value();
    $val_nonce = NONCE_RANDVALUE;
    $headers['X-Content-Security-Policy'] = "default-src 'self'; script-src unsafe-hashes 'self' https://milyin.com 'nonce-" . $val_nonce . "' https:; object-src 'none';base-uri 'none';img-src https: data:;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https:;report-uri https://milyin.com/?csp=true";
    return $headers;

}
add_filter( 'wp_headers', 'pagely_security_headers' );
```

So, we need to solve 2 things.

1.) It does not update the value of nonce, refreshing page and opening new tab still use the same value of nonce, diluting the entire purpose of nonces.

2.) A better way to echo the nonce elsewhere as I want inline scripts not registered in Wordpress to also have the nonce.

Also, I read CSP requires base64 nonces, are these nonces base64?

Comment: What you’re asking for is not an intended use case for WordPress nonces. WordPress nonces last up to 24 hours. If you want “true” nonces you would need to implement that yourself.

Comment: And How to do that for a wordpress site?

Comment: You can try passing a random value every time, something like `wp_create_nonce(wp_hash_password(md5(rand(1000, 50000))));`, this will create a random nonce every time.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast as stated here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69116549/how-to-allow-inline-js-scripts-using-nonces-for-csp it needs to be a base64 value... To be honest I don't even understand what base64 means, but random ints between 1000 to 5000 probably aren't base64 because as far as I know from the examples it looks far more uglier than Integers like these

Comment: The output of nonce is something you can use for csp? if yes then my code will work fine, wp_create_nonce is still responsible for the output, so I see no problem with it working. Try and let me know

Comment: Well, I have literally no knowledge about it, what I do know is that I need the code to be base64. The nonce value has to be base64

Comment: Ok so you can wrap the wp_create_nonce in PHPs, `base64_encode`, so something like this `base64_encode(wp_create_nonce(wp_hash_password(md5(rand(1000, 50000)))));`. At this point I would not even use wp_create_nonce as you only need a base64, but do tests with both.

Comment: Yeah... That was my point, I was wondering what are these functions for? I mean wouldn't just `base64_encode(random(1000,5000))` be enough...? I know the function `wp_create_nonce` but do we even need `md5()` and `wp_hash_password`?

Comment: If what you need is a random base64 every entry, then it should be enough. If you want a truly random base64 I would use my example, the possibility of a repeating base64 output is almost non existing.

Comment: I will try your code and will let you know.  Would suggest you to submit an answer regardless of explaining in comments, for making it easier for others and get the bounty incase your answer works..... :-)

Comment: Another problem, how to pass the base64 thingy created to both the functions? One for adding it to header other to add it script tags.. If I paste the `base64_encode(wp_create_nonce(wp_hash_password(md5(rand(1000, 50000)))));` in both functions, it would generate different nonces. What would be the right approach? Global Variable? something else? I want such that it can be echoed at places where the scripts are loaded without wordpress enqueue... So I want a way to put the nonce at multiple places...

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to add the nonce value to the <script> tags that aren't loaded into wordpress properly?  And, you are right, i just checked my site, and the nonce does not refresh each time i reload the page.  I was expecting it to change.  Looks like I have some more work to do :)

Comment: Well, I have figured it out. Mostly works. I use the_content filter and use str_replace wherever needed. I am using a bit customized approach for my site to comply with caching plugins.... But in general str_replace is the solution no better way to handle Inline JS or JS that is not added via enququ

Answer (score 0):

I have refered your questions discussion reagrding the adding of nonce csp in wordpress scripts.Please check my findings
I have created a function in functions.php of my theme

```
//creating random nonce for script-src CSP header
function generate_custom_nonce(){
    $created_nonce = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
    return wp_create_nonce($created_nonce);
}
```

In my header.php , I have added the code for headers and call the nonce whenever needed

```
$nonce=generate_custom_nonce();
header("Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'nonce-".$nonce."';");

<script type="text/javascript" nonce="<?php echo $nonce; ?>">
        dosomething....
</script>
```

This is the only and easiest method worked for me. For inbuild wordpress js codes, with the help of CSP hash generator added the hashed code in script-src directive.